# Checking if String is in a command answer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, raspberry-pi

I'm struggling with a problem in linux bash.
I want a script to execute a command

```
curl -s --head http://myurl/ | head -n 1
```

and if the result of the command contains 200 it executes another command.
Else it is echoing something. 
What i have now:

```
CURLCHECK=curl -s --head http://myurl | head -n 1
            if [[ $($CURLCHECK) =~ "200" ]]
            then
            echo "good"
            else
            echo "bad"
            fi
```

The script prints:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
bad
```

I tried many ways but none of them seems to work.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
if curl -s --head http://myurl | head -n 1 | grep "200" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo good
else
    echo bad
fi
```

Comment: +1: Note that `grep -q` is mandated by posix, so should be considered portable.

Comment: `>& /dev/null` for short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this curl command with `-w "%{http_code}"` to just get http status code:

```
[[ $(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -A "Chrome" -L "http://myurl/" -o /dev/null) == 200 ]] &&
      echo "good" || echo "bad"
```

Comment: I still get `bad` as output. But thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually capture the output from the curl command:

```
CURLCHECK=$(curl -s --head http://myurl | head -n 1)
```

I'm surprised you're not getting a "-s: command not found" error

Comment: Thanks, but even when i did this. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

using wget

```
 if wget -O /dev/null your_url 2>&1 | grep -F HTTP >/dev/null 2>&1 ;then echo good;else echo bad; fi
```